# Modules are not being loaded/consulted?

Tags: module, prolog

I need to use modules in my application, however they are not being consulted.

In `program.pl` I have the following code:

```
use_module("/modules/schedule_printer.pl").
```

In `schedule_printer.pl`:

```
:- module(schedule_printer).
```

However, when I type `consult("program.pl").`
it says it doesn't know the schedule_printer, when using a predicate that requires it.

By typing `consult("modules/schedule_printer.pl").`
it works. However, I don't want to have to manually consult all the modules every time. I tried changing the path, no slash in front, absolute path etc, but nothing works.

Am I doing something wrong?

Note: I am using SWIPL on Mac.

Comment: Do you write `:- use_module(...).` or `use_module(...).` ?

Comment: In program.pl: `use_module` without `:-`. In schedule_printer: `:- module().` See my edit, I added the schedule_printer.pl contents. Thanks!

Comment: ... and to keep the system up-do-date in SWI, simply type `make.`

Comment: I've made a big application, but just consulted different files using `:- [].` because I couldn't get the modules to work. I'm very familiar with `make.` now, but it doesn't work. I must be doing something wrong. Do I need to also add a consult to the module file, next to the `use_module()`?

Comment: in program.pl, put a directive `:- use_module(schedule_printer).`

Comment: @CapelliC should I also consult the module file `schedule_printer.pl`? Only adding this, gives me a bunch of errors  `source_sink  schedule_printer' does not exist`.

Comment: I use - for instance - `user:file_search_path(carlo, '/home/carlo/prolog').` and then :- use_module(carlo(a_module)). So try to add the right path to your root folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, in the module file, add:

```
:- module(<module_name>, [<export_predicates>]).
```

And in the program file, where you want to use the module, write the following:

```
:- use_module('<folder>/<module_name>.pl').
```

It doesn't work with double quotes on the use_module, also do not put a `/` at the beginning.